# How to create unique ref for nested v-for?

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I've got a nest array of objects, like this:

```
    taskList: [{
      taskName: "Number One"
    },{
      taskName: "Number Two",
      children: [{
        taskName: "Child One"
      },{
        taskName: "Child due"
      }]
    },{
      taskName: "Number Three"
      }]}
```

I loop through this list with a nested v-for and create an input for every element like this:

```
  <div v-for="(task, index) in taskList">
      <input :ref="'inputField' + index" type="text" v-model="task.taskName" @keydown.up="arrowPress(index, -1)">
      <div v-for="(childOne, childOneIndex) in task.children">
            <input ref="inputField" type="text" v-model="task.taskName" @keydown.up="arrowPress(childOneIndex, -1)">
```

I've setup an event that allows me to **move focus up/down through these inputs with arrow-keys**. The method for it looks like this:

```
      arrowPress(index, value) {
      this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs['inputField'+ (value + index)][0].focus());
      }
```

This works well for the parent.

But I want to be able to move between the children as well. I.e. with focus in "Number 3" when I press up I want to go to "Child Two" and then to "Child One" and then to "Number Two", etc.

I can see some solutions to this but haven't figured out how to get any of them to work:

1. Change `:ref="'inputField' + index"` to `ref="inputField"`. But how do I then know what inputField is calling to change it +-1? E.g. how to I go from inputField2 to inputField1 in my method?
2. Add a general counter that does ++ whenever an input is added, and use `:ref="'inputField' + counter"`. However whenever I try to do that by adding `{{counter++}}` after the v-for div I get an infite loop.
3. Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you calling `arrowPress` from a prop in the children or are you coping the function? Reason being if you use a prop from the parent you can call a child function or use an event listener

Comment: Currently it is in the same component, but it will likely be moved to a child component in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to make your references regular and sortable, then find your current position in the sorted list of refs to figure out which is the correct previous ref.

For example, make a method to compute the ref from indexes, so you don't need to repeat the code.  In this case, I made the ref be 'inputFieldXXXXYYYY' where XXXX is the parent index and YYYY is the child index:

```
    ref(parent, child) {
        let me = 'inputField' + parent.toString().padStart(4, '0');
        if (child !== undefined) me += child.toString().padStart(4, '0');
        return me;
    },
```

Then in your template use ref(index) for the parent, and ref(index, childIndex) for the children:

```
<div id="main">
    <div v-for="(task, index) in taskList">
        <input :ref="ref(index)" type="text" v-model="task.taskName" @keydown.up="arrowPress(index)">
        <div v-for="(child, childIndex) in task.children">
            <input :ref="ref(index, childIndex)" type="text" v-model="task.taskName" @keydown.up="arrowPress(index, childIndex)">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your arrowPress function, the children are found in the sorted list in the correct place, and you can decrement the index to find the previous reference:

```
    arrowPress(parent, child) {
        let refs = Object.keys(this.$refs).filter(key => key.indexOf('inputField') === 0).sort();
        let i = refs.indexOf(this.ref(parent, child));
        i = Math.max(i - 1, 0);
        let prevRef = refs[i];
        this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs[prevRef][0].focus());
    }
```

This works for up-arrow presses.  You can see how it would extend to down-arrows.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jmbldwn/a1sjk75r/24/

Per comments, here's a potentially simpler way that involves flattening the structure, then using a single v-for in the template:

https://jsfiddle.net/jmbldwn/u0anzm35/7/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When trying your fiddle focus moves fine except from Child One. From there it skips the parent (Number Two) and instead goes to Number One.

Comment: Oops, my bad.  0 !== undefined.  Fixed!

Comment: Thank you for your help with this! It does indeed work now both ways. I still wonder though if there isn't an "easier" solution to this.

Comment: Of course, there could be.  One way might be to flatten the data structure first into a simple array, where index would be monotonic and deterministic.  Not sure if that's simpler or not.

Comment: Added a fiddle with the flattening approach.  It loses the parent-child relationships, so it might have a downside depending on what else your app is doing.

Comment: Wow, you seem to be on fire tonight :-) I'll check it out. But still, wouldn't it be possible to simply have a variable that we do ++ on every time any v-for is run? Then that variable could be used to :ref="'inputField' + variable". I tried putting this in myself but keep getting infinite loops due to rerenders.

Comment: There's no easy way to have state within a v-for loop that I know of.  I always end up doing this kind of thing with methods or computed properties.